# JMeter: malformed result xml

Tags: jmeter

We experienced a strange issue sporadically, that the jmeter test result xml is malformed, for example two lines are swapped by each other, which makes the xml invalid at all. We execute jmeter test cases through command line. Anyone has such experience? Thanks.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There are no known bug related to this.

If you confirm that without any 3rd party plugin you face this issue, then please report a bug to jmeter:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html

They will be happy to fix it ASAP.

Provide a simple test plan, how you are exporting XML (which listener or is it through -l ?) , user.properties and jmeter.properties and jmeter.log.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try to find some clues on how to reproduce the issue with a test plan.